# is there any possibility to maintain 5 latest versions of major file in MySql Db?

Tags: java, mysql

Subject::::is there any possibility to maintain 5 latest versions of major file in MySql Db?

According to my proj req't i need to maintain latest 5 versions of file in MySql DB,
if the version count reached to 6 i've to delete first version of the file automatically..

is there any path to achieve to this requirement
if any plz help me .Thanks in advance

Comment: What thoughts do you have?  What has your research uncovered so far?  Have you tried something with which you would like some help?

Comment: Do not use shortcuts in description.it leads to further confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you store the file in a data column, you can add a `versions_back` column, and use it in `update` and `delete` statements, like this:

Table structure:

```
id versions_back data <other columns>
-- ------------- ---- ---------------
10       0       .... ....
12       1       .... ....
13       2       .... ....
15       3       .... ....
17       4       .... ....
```

Performing an insertion:

```
update versioned_file set versions_back=versions_back+1
insert into versioned_file(data, versions_back) values (<file-data>, 0)
delete versioned_file where versions_back >= 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by creating a database table like this

```
File History
------------
File History ID
File History Date
File
```

Just keep the most recent 5 rows.

Comment: Which of course begs the question ... how do you keep the most recent 5 rows?

Comment: @Stephen C: Insert row, get row count, if row count > 5 delete oldest row.  Use any programming language you wish.

Comment: Oh ... I thought you might have some way of doing it in (just) SQL.

Comment: @Stephen C: I'm just a simple SQL coder.  Select, insert, update, and delete.  I use Cobol or Java to combine the simple SQL into transactions.  None of that fancy SQL for me, like outer joins.